# Is it true that you need to be always online for a game once you download a DLC for the PS4?

Tags: ps4

I've read somewhere that when you download any DLC for any game on the PS4, you need to be online always afterwards to play that game. Any truth to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly. Basically any item that you buy from the store (either DLC or full game) will stay activated for a certain period of time after you've disconnected from the net (I'm not sure how long, but from experience I'd say about week or so). If you open the options menu (for the game/dlc in question) from the ribbon screen and select show information it should say how long the product is "activated" for.

(I could be using some of the words/terms as I'm not at home to check at the moment)

Comment: The same happens for fuil games downloaded through the store.